# How to group and assign values of dictionary into single key in python

Tags: python

I have the memory of intel hex file

```
1879048192: 4,
1879048193: 3,
1879048194: 2,
1879048195: 1,
1879048196: 4,
1879048197: 3,
1879048198: 2,
1879048199: 1,
1879048200: 4,
1879048201: 3,
1879048202: 2,
1879048203: 1,
1879048204: 4,
1879048205: 3,
1879048206: 2,
1879048207: 1,
```

I want to  have

```
1879048192: 1234(with swapping),
1879048196 :1234
1879048200 :1234
1879048204 :1234
1879048208 :1234
```

I using

```
for x in range (0,count):
    for i in range(0,4):
        realdata = mapFile.values()[x:x+4]
        realdata[x+3],realdata[x+2],realdata[x+1],realdata[x+0] =                realdata[x+0],realdata[x+1],realdata[x+2],realdata[x+3]

        s = ''.join(map(str, realdata))

        realadr = mapFile.keys()[x] + offset

        offset = offset + 4

        _buf = {realadr : int(s)}
```

But I am not able to success, I am new to python. Please suggest me the better implementation.

Comment: What does "with swapping" mean? Will the numbers in the first column of the input file always be sequential integers? Will the numbers in the second column of the input file always be 4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1...? Why does the first line in the output have the space after the colon, and all the other lines have the space before the colon?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want                                                                                        1879048192: 4,
1879048193: 3,
1879048194: 2,
1879048195: 1           1879048192:1234 1[value of 1879048195] 2[value of 1879048194] 3[value of 1879048193] 4[value of 1879048191] Since I am converting big endian to small endian system. Please help on this.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to use two digit hex numbers to represent each byte.  Otherwise you will have place errors when concatenating them.

Answer (score 0):

```
_buf = {realaddr : int(s)}
```

causes _buf to be a dictionary with a single entry, the last values of realaddr: int(s). That's not what you want. Move it outside and also add logic for merging the values:

```
_buf = {}
for x in range (0,count):
    for i in range(0,4):
        realdata = mapFile.values()[x:x+4]
        realdata[x+3],realdata[x+2],realdata[x+1],realdata[x+0] =                realdata[x+0],realdata[x+1],realdata[x+2],realdata[x+3]

        s = ''.join(map(str, realdata))

        realadr = mapFile.keys()[x] + offset

        offset = offset + 4

        if realadr in _buf:
           # merge the values somehow
           s = _buf[realadr] + s

        _buf[realadr] = int(s)

print _buf
```

Comment: Its throwing this error realdata[x+3],realdata[x+2],realdata[x+1],realdata[x+0] = realdata[x+0],realdata[x+1],realdata[x+2],realdata[x+3]
IndexError: list index out of range , I am using this swap the variable in the list.

Comment: @Sandy That's your code. I assumed you know what you're doing there. Feel free to replace it with anything that builds the keys/values you want in the final dictionary (i.e. should give,for example, realadr=1879048207 and s="1" ).

Comment: I need help on that also, could you please recommend something.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite using the mapfile.keys() in the for loop, as you wanted.  I used a generator object to enforce the step 4.  You want to process four bytes at a time, so you have to skip ahead four each time, and then you look ahead inside the loop to get mapfile[x+3].

You will notice I added some errors to the mapfile on purpose to demonstrate how the code handles them.

```
mapfile = {
    1879048192: 0,
    1879048193: 0,
    1879048194: 0,
    1879048195: 0,
    1879048196: 4,
    1879048197: 3,
    1879048198: 2,
    1879048199: 17,
    1879048200: 0,
    1879048201: 1,
    1879048202: 0,
    1879048203: 0,
    1879048204: 4,
    # intentionally missing byte
    1879048206: 2,
    1879048207: 1,
    1879048208: 0 # single byte cannot make up a dword
}

_buf = {}
for x in (x for x in mapfile.keys() if 0==x%4):
    try:
        s = "0x{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}{3:02x}".format(mapfile[x+3],mapfile[x+2],mapfile[x+1],mapfile[x+0])
        print "offset ", x, " value ", s
        _buf[x] = int(s, 16)
    except KeyError as e:
        print "bad key ", e

print "_buf is ", _buf
```

Output:

```
offset  1879048192  value  0x00000000
offset  1879048196  value  0x11020304
offset  1879048200  value  0x00000100
bad key  1879048205
bad key  1879048211
_buf is  {1879048192: 0, 1879048200: 256, 1879048196: 285344516}
```

Comment: But this is defeating my purpose, its not giving the proper address, if I do this.   _buf = {}
for x in range (offset,offset+count,4):
    realdata = mapFile.values()
    s = "{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}{3:02x}".format(realdata[x+3],realdata[x+2],realdata[x+1],realdata[x+0])
    #print "offset ", x, " value ", s # optional for debugging
    _buf[x] = s
    pprint(_buf) What I am doing is right? But I want 32 bit address, it is giving only 16 bit address

Comment: Thanks @ Kenny Ostrom, addresses = mapFile.keys()

i = 0
val32 = 0
for addr in addresses:
   if i == 4:
      print hex(val32)
      val32 = 0
      i = 0
   addr32 = addr & 0xFFFFFFFC
   offset = addr - addr32
   value = mapFile[addr]
   val32 = val32 | (value << offset *8)
   i = i +1

print hex(val32) I used this, its working fine . how to handle end cases? How to handle alignment and missing alignment? Could you please give me the procedure or sample snippet based on above code

Comment: For alignment, you want to start at a dword boundary.  This means the starting address satisfies this condition: address % 4 == 0, where address is the byte offset.

Comment: For end cases, if you have some number of bytes at the end which is not exactly 4, then you have to either toss them, or assume the remaining bytes are 0.  You can only work on four bytes at a time without getting an index out of range exception.  Or, instead of trying to trim or pad, you can detect this in the loop condition so you only process addresses with all 4 bytes available, or just catch the exception and ignore it.

Comment: if the byte by byte data map is missing any entries, that will also trigger an index out of range exception, which I think should just fail the whole operation with an appropriate message.  But you could just skip that address in the _buf output.

Comment: I'm definitely getting 32 bit addresses when I run it.

Comment: but could you please tell me where real data should initialize realdata = mapFile.values()  like this I have to do after for loop?

Comment: realdata looks like a temporary holding place for the four bytes you are working on.  I skipped the temporary and just used mapfile[x], mapfile[x+1] etc directly inside the format statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kenny Ostrom for the inputs1879048205: Can I pad "Zero", by removing exception 1879048208 -- Can I pad four "bytes" remained in Dword . Is it affect the hex code if we pad zero?

Comment: You can handle it however you like.  For example, use defaultdict(int) so it returns 0 when you ask for a missing index.

Comment: except KeyError as e:
        defaultdict(int)   Is it like this? could you please elaborate? I'm new to python.

Comment: No, once you hit an exception, you have two options: catch and crash.  If you use collections.defaultdoct(int) instead of dict, then it will not raise a KeyError, but instead will add that key to the dict with a default value of 0 and keep going.  I think you should just catch the exception like I did, and not try to "fix" errors in the map file.

Comment: from collections import defaultdict                                                            buf = {}
for x in (x for x in mapFile.keys() if 0==x%4): buf[x] = int(s, 16) still through an exception                                                                                 s = "0x{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}{3:02x}".format(mapFile[x+3],mapFile[x+2],mapFile[x+1],mapFile[x+0])
KeyError: 1879048215 I am missing something?

Comment: The for loop says we have mapFile[x], but we're trying to access mapFile[x+3].  That's the KeyError.  It should be there, but it's not in the data I put up there, specifically to create and test the error handling.  Now ... if mapFile is a defaultdict, then it can just return 0 instead of raising a KeyError.

Comment: mapFile = defaultdict(int)                                                                        buf = defaultdict(int)
for x in (x for x in mapFile.keys() if 0==x%4):                                            s = "0x{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}{3:02x}".format(mapFile[x+3],mapFile[x+2],mapFile[x+1],mapFile[x+0])  _buf[x] = int(s, 16) but still throwing an error. KeyError: 1879048215 although I used default dictionary